# Difference between skipBytes and skip of DataInputStream?

Tags: java, java-me, inputstream

I wonder now, what is the difference between the two methods:

`DataInputStream.skipBytes` and `DataInputStream.skip`.

I am aware of the fact that `skip` must come from `InputStream` and `skipBytes` from `DataInput`, but still, is there any *difference*. You know, when using streams in J2ME, things get pretty tricky so I *need* to know!

Would the Input/DataInput Streams returned from the `FileConnection` in JSR-75 be any different in handling than any other such streams?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from `DataInputStream` :

```
public final int skipBytes(int n) throws IOException {
    int total = 0;
    int cur = 0;

    while ((total<n) && ((cur = (int) in.skip(n-total)) > 0)) {
        total += cur;
    }

    return total;
    }
```

as you can see from the code, `skipBytes` uses  `skip (InputStream.skip)`

the only thing that i can say is that if data in your wrapped inputStream (InputStream inside DataInputStream)changes by another **thread**, then  the result of skipBytes and skip may be different. but if your application just working with single thread then skipBytes and skip are the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It explains it then.

Comment: `in.skip(x)` (which is also called via `skip()`) isn't guaranteed to skip x bytes, which is why skipBytes of DataInputStream uses this loop. However, since `InputStream.skip()` is allowed to return zero as per [the contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#skip%28long%29), even `skipBytes` isn't guaranteed to skip (loop will exit if one skip returned 0).

Answer (score 4):

Also, skip() takes a long as an argument, so you can skip over many more bytes at a time.  Useful for large files

Answer (score 0):

If you try to use *.skip()* to return back instead of moving forward. You will notice that it will successfully get back in bytes. However, if you try to go back in bytes using *skipBytes()*, let's say you want to move 10 bytes back *dis.skipBytes(n)*, it won't work, it will stay the same. So, in conclusion this is the main difference between *skip* and *skipBytes*. Another difference is that, *skip(long i)*, *skipBytes(int i)*, skip takes a *long* type which gives you the ability to skip more bytes for larger files.